# automate publishing Revit models to ACC more than once a week

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation, autodesk-construction-cloud

I would like to set up our Revit modes to publish to ACC more frequently than once a week. I'm assuming I would use the Design Automation API for this, but it's unclear. Is there any documentation? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for this API?

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/PublishModel/